# form fileds not coming to next line on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am designing  an application which is working fine for desktop

[image]

but in case of mobile devices form fields are not coming to next line.

On mobile devices all fields seems truncated.
[image]
I want them bring on next line like[image]
Here is my form element

```
<div class="inner cover">

                    <p class="lead">&nbsp;</p>

                     <form class="form-inline" method="get" action="search.html"   id="search-hotel-form">
                        <a href="#" id="find" style="display:none;">Find</a>
                        <div class="input-group input-group-sm" style="margin:auto;">

                            <select class="selectpicker form-control input-lt" tvalue="" id="city">
                                <option value="null" selected="selected">Your location</option>
                                <option value="delhi">X</option>
                                <option value="gurgaon">Y</option>
                            </select>
                            <span class="input-group-btn" style="width:0px;"></span>
                            <div style="position:relative;"><input id="datetimepicker" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Check In" style="margin-left:-2px;"/></div>
                            <input type='text' tvalue="" id="datetimepicker1" hidden="hidden"/>
                            <span class="input-group-btn" style="width:0px;"></span>
                            <select class="selectpicker form-control" style="margin-left:-1px;" id="checkout">
                                <option value="0" selected="selected">Stay Hours</option>
                                <option value="1">X</option>
                                <option value="2">Y</option>
                            </select>
                            <input type='text' tvalue="" id="datetimepicker2" hidden="hidden"/>
                            <span class="input-group-btn" style="width:0px;"></span>
                            <select class="selectpicker form-control" style="margin-left:-2px;" th:field="*{adults}" id="guest">
                                <option value="0" selected="selected">No. of guests</option>
                                <option value="1">1 student</option>
                                <option value="2">2 student</option>

                            </select>
                            <span class="input-group-btn" style="width:0px;"></span>
                            <button type="text" class="form-control btn btn-success" style="margin-left:-1px;">Find the Best Hotels &raquo;</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <div class="map_canvas" style="display:none; width:400px; height:300px;"></div>
                </div>
```

and css that I have written for this is

```
   /*
 * Globals
 */

/* Links */
a,
a:focus,
a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

/* Custom default button */
.btn-default,
.btn-default:hover,
.btn-default:focus {
  color: #333;
  text-shadow: none; /* Prevent inheritence from `body` */
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}


/*
 * Base structure
 */

html,
body {
  height:  100%;
  background-color: #333;
  background-image: url('/resources/img/home.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
}
body {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: none; //0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}

/* Extra markup and styles for table-esque vertical and horizontal centering */
.site-wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; /* For at least Firefox */
  min-height: 100%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 100px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
          box-shadow: inset 0 0 100px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}
.site-wrapper-inner {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.cover-container {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

/* Padding for spacing */
.inner {
  padding: 30px;
}


/*
 * Header
 */
.masthead-brand {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.masthead-nav > li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.masthead-nav > li + li {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.masthead-nav > li > a {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #fff; /* IE8 proofing */
  color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
}
.masthead-nav > li > a:hover,
.masthead-nav > li > a:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #fff;
  border-bottom-color: rgba(255,255,255,.3);
}
.masthead-nav > .active > a,
.masthead-nav > .active > a:hover,
.masthead-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom-color: #fff;
}
.btn-home {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: normal !important;
}

.input-group input,
.input-group select {
  width: 72px !important;
}

.input-group input,
.input-group select {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8) !important;
  border: none !important;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.input-group > .input-lt {
    border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px !important;
}

.input-group > .input-rt {
    border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0 !important;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .masthead-brand {
    float: left;
  }
  .masthead-nav {
    float: right;
  }
}


/*
 * Cover
 */

.cover {
  padding: 0 20px;
}
.cover .btn-lg {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-weight: normal;
}


/*
 * Footer
 */

.mastfoot {
  color: #999; /* IE8 proofing */
  color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}


/*
 * Affix and center
 */

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  /* Pull out the header and footer */
  .masthead {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
  }
  .mastfoot {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
  }
  /* Start the vertical centering */
  .site-wrapper-inner {
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  /* Handle the widths */
  .masthead,
  .mastfoot,
  .cover-container {
    width: 100%; /* Must be percentage or pixels for horizontal alignment */
  }
  .input-group .form-control {
    width: 120px !important;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .masthead,
  .mastfoot,
  .cover-container {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .input-group .form-control {
    width: 160px !important;
  }

  .input-group .input-lt {
    width: 320px !important;
  }
}

.shadowed {
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2));
    filter: url(#drop-shadow);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Dropshadow(OffX=12, OffY=12, Color='#444')";
    filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Dropshadow(OffX=12, OffY=12, Color='#444')";
}

.selectpicker {
  color: grey;
}
select option:first-child {
  color: grey;
  display: none;
}
select option {
  color: #555;
}
```

I am using bootstrap.  Please someone guide me to make form field comes on next line on mobile devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least one issue is your entire form is inside `class="input-group input-group-sm"` which is restricting any change of orientation.

The inline styles have also been removed.

Maybe this will help, probably depends on your overall layout or other elements that may be on the page.

```css
/*
 * Globals
 */

/* Links */
 a, a:focus, a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}
/* Custom default button */
 .btn-default, .btn-default:hover, .btn-default:focus {
    color: #333;
    text-shadow: none;
    /* Prevent inheritence from `body` */
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}
/*
 * Base structure
 */
 html, body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #333;
    background-image: url('http://img0.gtsstatic.com/wallpapers/f11634bfd85724cc44858fa49c489167_large.jpeg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
}
body {
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: none;
    //0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
/* Extra markup and styles for table-esque vertical and horizontal centering */
 .site-wrapper {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    /* For at least Firefox */
    min-height: 100%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 100px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 100px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
.site-wrapper-inner {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.cover-container {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
/* Padding for spacing */
 .inner {
    padding: 30px;
}
/*
 * Header
 */
 .masthead-brand {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.masthead-nav > li {
    display: inline-block;
}
.masthead-nav > li + li {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.masthead-nav > li > a {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #fff;
    /* IE8 proofing */
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
}
.masthead-nav > li > a:hover, .masthead-nav > li > a:focus {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-bottom-color: #fff;
    border-bottom-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
}
.masthead-nav > .active > a, .masthead-nav > .active > a:hover, .masthead-nav > .active > a:focus {
    color: #fff;
    border-bottom-color: #fff;
}
.btn-home {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: normal !important;
}
.cover .btn-lg {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.selectpicker {
    color: grey;
}
select option:first-child {
    color: grey;
    display: none;
}
select option {
    color: #555;
}
.no-gutter >[class*='col-'] {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
/*
 * Footer
 */
 .mastfoot {
    color: #999;
    /* IE8 proofing */
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}
.form-control, .form-control:focus {
    box-shadow: none;
    font-size: 12px !important;
}
input, select, select option {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) !important;
    color: #555 !important;
    border: none !important;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .form-control.input-lt {
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;
        border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px !important;
    }
    .form-control.input-rt {
        border: none !important;
        outline: 0;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;
        border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0 !important;
        border-top: 1px solid #5cb85c;
        border-right: 1px solid #5cb85c;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #5cb85c;
    }
    .form-control.input-rt:hover, .form-control.input-rt:focus {
        border: none !important;
        outline: 0;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;
        border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0 !important;
        border-top: 1px solid #449d44;
        border-right: 1px solid #449d44;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #449d44;
    }
    .input-ct::-webkit-input-placeholder {
        color: #555 !important;
    }
    .input-ct:-moz-placeholder {
        /* Firefox 18- */
        color: #555 !important;
    }
    .input-ct::-moz-placeholder {
        /* Firefox 19+ */
        color: #555 !important;
    }
    .input-ct:-ms-input-placeholder {
        color: #555 !important;
    }
    .form-control.input-ct {
        outline: 0;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;
        border-radius: 0 !important;
    }
    .masthead-brand {
        float: left;
    }
    .masthead-nav {
        float: right;
    }
    /* Pull out the header and footer */
    .masthead {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
    }
    .mastfoot {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
    }
    /* Start the vertical centering */
    .site-wrapper-inner {
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    /* Handle the widths */
    .masthead, .mastfoot, .cover-container {
        width: 100%;
        /* Must be percentage or pixels for horizontal alignment */
    }
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .form-control.input-lt {
        outline: 0;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;
        border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0 !important;
    }
    .form-control.input-rt {
        border: none !important;
        outline: 0;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;
        border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px !important;
        border-left: 1px solid #5cb85c;
        border-right: 1px solid #5cb85c;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #5cb85c;
    }
    .form-control.input-rt:hover, .form-control.input-rt:focus {
        border: none !important;
        outline: 0;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;
        border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px !important;
        border-left: 1px solid #449d44;
        border-right: 1px solid #449d44;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #449d44;
    }
    .form-control.input-ct {
        outline: 0;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;
        border-radius: 0 !important;
    }
    .container.cover {
        padding: 0 40px;
    }
    .input-ct::-webkit-input-placeholder {
        padding-left: 5px;
        color: #555 !important;
    }
    .input-ct:-moz-placeholder {
        /* Firefox 18- */
        padding-left: 5px;
        color: #555 !important;
    }
    .input-ct::-moz-placeholder {
        /* Firefox 19+ */
        padding-left: 5px;
        color: #555 !important;
    }
    .input-ct:-ms-input-placeholder {
        padding-left: 5px;
        color: #555 !important;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .masthead, .mastfoot, .cover-container {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
.shadowed {
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
    filter: url(#drop-shadow);
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Dropshadow(OffX=12, OffY=12, Color='#444')";
    filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Dropshadow(OffX=12, OffY=12, Color='#444')";
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container cover">
  <p class="lead">&nbsp;</p>
  <form class="form-horizontal" method="get" action="search.html" id="search-hotel-form"> <a href="#" id="find" style="display:none;">Find</a>

    <div class="row no-gutter">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <select class="selectpicker form-control input-lt" tvalue="" id="city">
          <option value="null" selected="selected">Your location</option>
          <option value="delhi">X</option>
          <option value="gurgaon">Y</option>
        </select> <span class="input-group-btn"></span> 
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <input id="datetimepicker" type="text" class="form-control input-ct" placeholder="Check In" />
        <input type="text" tvalue="" id="datetimepicker1" hidden="hidden" /> <span class="input-group-btn"></span> 
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <select class="selectpicker form-control input-ct" id="checkout">
          <option value="0" selected="selected">Stay Hours</option>
          <option value="1">X</option>
          <option value="2">Y</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" tvalue="" id="datetimepicker2" hidden="hidden" /> <span class="input-group-btn"></span> 
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <select class="selectpicker form-control input-ct" th:field="*{adults}" id="guest">
          <option value="0" selected="selected">No. of Guests</option>
          <option value="1">1 student</option>
          <option value="2">2 student</option>
        </select> <span class="input-group-btn"></span> 
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <button type="text" class="form-control btn btn-success input-rt">Find the Best Hotels &raquo;</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  <div class="map_canvas" style="display:none; width:400px; height:300px;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: can u tell me magic behind single input box on airbnb  which shows multiple input boxes once user click single  given box. it clearly visible once u launched their website on mobile

Comment: That's actually a fake search field (just a div) that then launches a modal with the actual search form.

Comment: can u please provide some demo with code snippet that u have provided ?

Comment: I'm more than happy to help you, but in keeping with how SO works you'll need to post a new question along with what you've tried. Feel free to let me know if you do post a question related to this.

Comment: @ vanburenx, I will try out then will ping you

Comment: I have posted my problem statement. Can you please look into that .  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31923693/how-to-hide-a-given-div-on-mobile-and-visible-on-desktop

Answer (score 0):

In the media query for mobile, give

```
input {
    display: block;
}
```

This will make them appear on the next line

Comment: Hi Sid, thanks for replying. I tried but it didn't work out .I hosted my app at http://stayuncle.com/home . Can please check your changes at your end. Please le me know if this is working

Comment: I have checked one more thing , whenever I  implement a form field in separate div its coming to next line but it also happen on desktop also.

Comment: @Nand check Vanburenx answer below, he already solved your problem :)